# What is it? --> a:5:{i:0;i:14357;i:1;i:14358;i:2;i:14359;i:3;i:14360;i:4;i:14361;}

Tags: serialization, woocommerce, post-meta

```
 a:5:{i:0;i:14357;i:1;i:14358;i:2;i:14359;i:3;i:14360;i:4;i:14361;}
```

serialize array in php without size and double quotes? It's stored in a wordpress woocommerce postmeta table as `meta_value`.

How can I build it from an array in php for insert in the db?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the wordpress functions of `get/set/add_post_meta`, Wordpress should automatically serialize and unserialize array data for you (assuming it's non-scalar data).